# VB6 to VBNet - ListBox.Selected

Tags: vb.net, vb6, listbox, vb6-migration

I currently have a select-case that will read a name field from a recordset, as well as read a boolean value from that recordset that is suppose determine whether or not to include that field in a report that will be generated later on.

The problem is, is that in VB6, you were able to assign a boolean value to ListBox.Selected(i)

Now, I cannot for the life of me figure out what to assign it to, to select or not select that field dependent on the boolean value within the recordset.

**Code:**

```
Do Until rs_1.EOF
        'Until we run out of records ...

        str_FieldName = rs_1.Fields("FieldName").Value
        b_IncludeField = rs_1.Fields("IncludeInBatchReport").Value

        Select Case str_FieldName
            Case "Sequence"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("Sequence")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
            Case "BldgNo"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("BldgNo")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
            Case "BldgName"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("BldgName")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
            Case "BldgFunc"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("BldgFunc")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
            Case "POC"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("POC")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
            Case "Phone"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("Phone")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
            Case "AH_Phone"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("AH_Phone")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
            Case "Batch"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("Batch")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
            Case "Status"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("Status")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
            Case "Region_Req"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("Region_Req")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
            Case "Region_Alt"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("Region_Alt")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
            Case "Region_Fin"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("Region_Fin")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
            Case "Comments"
                listbox_Fields.Items.Add("Comments")
                listbox_Fields.SelectedItem(listbox_Fields.Items.Count - 1) = b_IncludeField
        End Select

        rs_1.MoveNext()

        '... until we run out of records.
    Loop
```

As you can see, I have tried SelectedItem, but that does not work of course.

Comment: Further to Slaks' answer, you could also look at using checkboxes in the list, whihc I thknk have the `.Checked()` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [`SetSelected(index, bool)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected.aspx).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. I will accept your answer in 7 minutes. Ha.